# Ddos attack on the ISP

Tags: ddos, internet, protection, isp

I need help in controlling my ISP from Ddos attacks it's happening for almost a month almost everyday bringing down the isp for 4 to 5 hours sometimes for the whole day anyone can help it guide what is the best and cheap solution to a kid this Ddos attacks on my isp
Kindly let me know what u need to have technical info from my side and solve this issue
TIA

Comment: What do you call ISP? I only use that for Internet Service Provider...

Comment: Are you just a customer of your Internet Service Provider? Unless your computer/network is infected with botware there's not much you can do to prevent DDOS